# Safari ignores media queries when "open new tabs in background" option is on. iPad iOS 5+

Tags: ios, css, ipad, mobile-safari, media-queries

I'm running into a problem where Safari on an iPad 2 running iOS 5.1.1 is ignoring media queries when opening a link into a new tab. This only happens when the "open new tabs in background" option is turned on.

You can view a simple example at: http://www.pauluscreative.com/mq/

To Reproduce the issue:

1. Hold the "test" link to bring up the menu.
2. Choose "open in new tab"

Ideally you should only see a blue box, the red should be hidden by the media query. The result is that you see both boxes.

I've used the following CSS:

```
<style>
    #red {  height: 40px; width: 40px; background-color: #FF0000;  }
    #blue {  height: 40px; width: 40px; background-color: #0000FF;  }

    @media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) {
            #red { display: none; }
    }

</style>
```

Is this a known issue, the expected behavior, a bad media query or an issue with Safari.

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: I never found a solution, but the issue was fixed in later versions of safari.

Answer (score 0):

In your provided example (the link) the media queries are missing.
But the test link points to another document where they are included.

Are you aware of that?

Comment: The test is not correct but the problem is valid. I have the same issue on iOS 5.1.1